# Bumblebee not disabeling NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee

I installed bumblebee to save some battery on my laptop. It works very well. When I boot the computer `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` says OFF. When i run an application with `primusrun`, `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` says ON as expected, but it doesn't go back to OFF when the application quits. I have seen questions about similar problems but no answers. The only thing I have found is that you can run `sudo rmmod nvidia && sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF` to disable the NVIDIA graphics card manually.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you trying to disable your graphics card? You kinda need that to stay on if you want to see anything on the screen.

Comment: I have two graphics cards, on from NVIDIA (which has better performance but draws more battery) and one from intel (which draws less battery but is not as good). I want to use the one from intel except when I am using a more demanding application such as a game. Once I am done playing I want to switch back to Intel's card to save battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same behaviour a while ago on Xubuntu 15.10 (64bit) with bumblebee and nvidia-355 (installed from [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)). There might to be some issues in Bumblebee with removing nvidia kernel module when it has a alias in modprobe.d, something to do with modprobe vs. insmod/rmmod I think.

**Warning: I tried other things before this one so this might or might not be the complete fix.**

Starting point was that I had an otherwise working configuration except NVIDIA GPU stayed on after running something with optirun. I then edited /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and commented out line (which probably get overwritten on driver updates and will have to be fixed again):

```
#alias nvidia nvidia_355
```

In /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf I use `Driver=nvidia` with these settings:

```
[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia_355
PMMethod=auto
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-355:/usr/lib32/nvidia-355
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-355/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

After this Bumblebee removes nvidia_355 kernel module ok and `optirun --status` reports "Discrete video card is off".

EDIT: removed commenting out "alias nvidia-uvm", tested and no need to comment out, might even be bad idea.

EDIT2: these settings should work also with nvidia-361 drivers if you update the settings above from "355" to "361". In addition with current bumblebee package from universe (3.2.1-9), you have to add blacklisting for 361 to `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` and add nvidia-modeset to the "remove line" at the end of the file i.e. change:

```
# Workaround to make sure nvidia-uvm is removed as well
remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia
```

to

```
# 361
blacklist nvidia-361
blacklist nvidia-361-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-361
# Workaround to make sure nvidia-uvm is removed as well
remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia
```

EDIT3:
with nvidia-364 change remove line to:

```
remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll test this later.

Comment: It didn't work. When i boot the computer it says "Discrete video card is off", and while running an application with primusrun it says "1 applications using bumblebeed". But when the application ends ti says "Discrete video card is on".  I am using nvidia-361 as my graphics driver by the way.

Comment: I too updated to nvidia-361 yesterday. I noticed that /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf has blacklisting only up to nvidia-355 so that is one thing you could try add for 361 and then there is a line at the end "remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia" which should probably be "remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia" (add nvidia-modeset). This at least with Xubuntu 15.10 and bumblebee from universe repository.

Comment: I did add the lines for blacklisting nvidia-361 but I didn't edit the last line. I'll try that aswell.

Comment: It works! `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` is missing so I couldn't edit that part, but it works anyway. Thank you.

Comment: After reinstallation nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf do exist and the line you mentioned had to be commented out. It seems like using NVIDIA X Server Settings gives slightly better performance.

Comment: Nice to hear you got it working. Actually nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf vanished for me too after upgrading to 361 and then reappeared after reinstalling the package. I thought I somehow removed it myself but maybe it's a feature. :) I'll edit the answer and add this stuff about 361 driver.

Comment: I recently updated my graphics driver to nvidia-364 and bumblebee doesn't work anymore. I tried replacing 361 with 364.

Comment: I had to edit the remove line in /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf to "remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia" and add the blacklisting lines for nvidia-364. Not sure anymore if that was all I did.

Comment: I get the following error message when running primusrun:
`primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/nvidia-364/xorg/libglx.so: libnvidia-tls.so.364.15: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
`

Comment: That error might be about primusrun not finding 64bit libraries. I would start by checking line "LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-364:/usr/lib32/nvidia-364" in bumblebee.conf for typos.

Comment: I reinstalled to make sure there wasn't any typos and now I'm getting a different error: `primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
`

Comment: Haven't had those issues with my laptop so I'm pretty much out of ideas. https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/580 seems to have the same error.

Comment: Now it works! I don't know what solved it because I changed two things. First of all I had read your instruction about the line starting with rmmod wrong which I corrected and in the link you posted there was a workaround to the problem which involved editing `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bumblebee and use nvidia-prime to disable NVIDIA and switch to intel graphics.
Bumblebee was replaced by nvidia-prime to switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics.

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

Open NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles -> select Intel -> log out and back in.

[image]

Comment: This method is the one I was using before and will probably be the one I switch back to. It is just very annoyning having to log out each time you change the settings.

Comment: @GKraft : Yes, you should do it - I suggest that when you use the PC for demanding tasks (like playing games), use the NVIDIA graphics and when you are using the PC for normal tasks, use intel graphics. :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with this method. It works much better.

Comment: I thought the aswer by @kk78 answered my original question better, even though your answer might actually be a better hting to do.