# After upgrade, nVidia card is ON by default

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

After a recent update on 16.04.1, which involved the nvidia drivers, the nvidia card (optimus) is turned on by default at every boot, causing overheating.

I can tell the card is on because `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` returns `0000:01:00.0 ON`. To turn it off I use `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF`.

In the past, when I was experimenting with nvidia drivers and the Xorg edgers PPA repo, I experienced a similar problem, which I solved by purging the repo and reinstalling the drivers in the Ubuntu repo. Since the latter is the driver I'm currently using, I wonder what I can now do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mixing solutions from [Bumblebee not disabeling NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735046/bumblebee-not-disabeling-nvidia/736993#736993) and http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html it seems that I have got everything back into place now.

Here are the steps that I have performed (modulo bad memory!)

1. Purge bumblebee* and primus*
2. Install `nvidia-prime`
3. Make sure that nvidia drivers are installed from System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers. I have tried nvidia-370, but it didn't work the first time. You can give it a try, but in the end I've got everything working with the proprietary driver nvidia-367.
4. `sudo prime-select intel` (if this fails the first time, a reboot might help).
5. Install the Bumblebee testing PPA `ppa:bumblebee/testing` and then install `bumblebee`
6. Blacklist the drivers you've opted for in `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`. In my case I had to add

   ```
   # 367
   blacklist nvidia-367
   blacklist nvidia-367-updates
   blacklist nvidia-experimental-367
   remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia
   ```

   Apparently the last line is crucial and the one thing that got this solution to really work for me (without that line I still got the nvidia card to work, but it turns ON automatically at boot and it won't turn OFF with `bbswitch`).
7. Configure `bumblebee` by editing `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. Look carefully for `Driver=` in the `[bumblebeed]` section. It is probably not necessary, but if it is blank after the `=`, just put `nvidia`. Then make sure you have these settings

   ```
   [driver-nvidia]
   KernelDriver=nvidia-367
   PMMethod=auto
   LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367:/usr/lib32/nvidia-367
   XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
   XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
   ```

   Replace 367 with your chosen version.
8. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
9. Reboot.

To test that everything is OK run the command:

```
`read a b <<< `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch`; echo "nVidia card at $a is $b"`
```

You should get

`nVidia card at 0000:01:00.0 is OFF`

By running `glxinfo` over `optirun`, for instance `optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, you should get something like this

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.57
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.57
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

which shows that the nvidia drivers are used by `optirun`.

Steps 6-8 can be automated with the following bash script.

```bsh
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "This script requires superuser privileges to run"
fi

sudo apt update

echo "Here is a list of (possibly) all the NVIDIA drivers available from your current software repositories"

apt-cache search nvidia- | grep "nvidia-[0-9]\+ - N"

echo -n "Enter the version that you wish to install and hit [ENTER]: "
read ver
echo $ver

echo "Installing the specified driver..."
sudo apt install -y nvidia-${ver}

echo -n "Removing duplicate entries in /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf... "
sed "/blacklist nvidia.\+$ver/d" /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf > bumblebee.conf
sed -i "/\#.\+$ver/d" bumblebee.conf
sed -i "/remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia/d" bumblebee.conf
echo "Done."

echo -n "Blacklisting the drivers... "
echo "# ${ver}" >> bumblebee.conf
echo "blacklist nvidia-${ver}" >> bumblebee.conf
echo "blacklist nvidia-${ver}-updates" >> bumblebee.conf
echo "blacklist nvidia-experimental-${ver}" >> bumblebee.conf
echo "remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia-uvm nvidia" >> bumblebee.conf
sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf.bak
sudo mv bumblebee.conf /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
echo "Done."

echo -n "Configuring Bumblebee... "
sed "s/^Driver=$/Driver=nvidia/g" /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf > bumblebee.conf
sed -i "s/^KernelDriver=nvidia-.*/KernelDriver=nvidia-${ver}/g" bumblebee.conf
sed -i "s|\(/usr/lib[32]*/nvidia-\)[^,:/\n]\+|\1${ver}|g" bumblebee.conf
sudo cp /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf.bak
sudo mv bumblebee.conf /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
echo "Done."

sudo update-initramfs -u

echo ""
echo "Please restart your system for the changes to take effect."
```